# How to send python pyrealsense2 object to another server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, realsense

I am using the [pyrealsense2](https://pypi.org/project/pyrealsense2/) library, which I use for the Intel Realsense D435 3D Camera.
I wanted to pickle the frame object, but its says TypeError not possible, and send it via a small flask server. Is there another way to send this python object to another server? I need to process it.
Thanks!

```
# Get 3D Frame
@app.route('/3D')
def get_3D():
    pipeline = rs.pipeline()
    pipeline.start()
    try:
        print("Get 3D Frame")
        # Remove old Pickle if exist
        if(os.path.isfile("3d.pkl")):
            os.remove("3d.pkl")
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
        if (depth_frame):
            # Create new pickle file
            with open('3d.pkl', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(depth_frame, f)
            return send_file('3d.pkl')

    finally:
        pipeline.stop()
```

Comment: I belive it maybe the wrapper needs pickabe function and it doesn't have it?

Comment: py::pickle() , Any way without having this? http://lira.no-ip.org:8080/doc/pybind11-doc/html/advanced/classes.html#pickling-support